# Log-minus-log-plots using `ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit()`

Tags: r, ggsurvfit

Is it possible to produce a log-minus-log plot using `ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit()`?

Here's an example of what I want to produce:

```
library(ggsurvfit)
temp <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ adhere, data = df_colon)
plot(temp, fun = \(x) log(-log(x)))
```

but instead of using `plot()` I want to use `ggsurvfit::ggsurvfit()`. I tried the following

```
temp$surv <- log(-log(temp$surv))
ggsurvfit(temp)
```

but it behaves weirdly in the beginning of the plot because the survival curve is 1 at time 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `ggsurvfit()` assumes that `y=1` at time zero. This makes sense for a survival curve - you can't model the survival of people who are already dead - but not if you transform the y-axis.

To resolve this, as `ggsurvit()` produces a `ggplot` object, you can just set the axis limits to only include values which are actually there, removing the row containing this assumption. I would change the y-axis label as well.

```r
ggsurvfit(temp) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = (c(min(temp$surv), max(temp$surv)))
    ) +
    labs(
        y = "log(-log(surival probability))"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting a feature request on the ggsurvfit GitHub repo? I wrote the package and I thought I allowed for custom transformations using the type argument, but the docs make it seem this is not possible...